# Where do memory leaks go in .NET applications

Tags: .net, unmanaged, managed

My .NET application has access to a c++ API via a .NET Assembly.
Lets assume I do not correctly release unmanaged resources/objects in my Dispose method.

Is the memory increasing only in the application.exe or can the memory leak also go outside the application.exe, so I can be sure when the application exits that I get all memeory back?

Comment: Can you show us some code?  Do you actually have a memory leak?  Is the C++ API standard C++ or is it managed C++?

Comment: If it's Managed C++ then it shouldn't leak, fingers crossed.  The AppDomain will eventually clean everything up, but memory utilization can still be high until it does.

Comment: If you are using Managed C++ to call Unmanaged (native) c++ code, that native code can cause a memory leak if it is expecting you to clean up the memory.

Comment: @MauriceReeves Managed C++ can be a mixed mode assembly, which means it can use `new` in addition to `gcnew`. The former is not handled by the GC.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski That is true.  Didn't consider that.  I think OP needs to post some code.  Too many variables at play here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .exe process.

You can use perfmon to monitor the process, and in the case of an unmanaged memory leak you will see the counter for total memory go up, but the .NET memory will remain the steady.

Use these PerfMon counters to do that:

Process/Private Bytes,
.NET CLR Memory/# Bytes in All Heaps,

In the case of an unchecked unmanaged memory leak (ie you continuously leak memory) your application will eventually crash.

And see this thread for more: [Detecting memory leak in mixed environment(Managed-Unmanaged)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045938/detecting-memory-leak-in-mixed-environmentmanaged-unmanaged)

Answer (score 0):

If you leak memory via an unmanaged API, it leaks just *as usual*. It will be lost inside the process memory space.

There's nothing unusual about .NET here.

Also, if your unmanaged lib allocates memory in a shared memory space... well, then it will leak there.