# Tool to monitor threads in C# application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am currenly analyzing my code and application for having resource leakage. How do I monitor a C# process for currently running threads?

Comment: What's wrong with [Visual studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15yf86f.aspx)?

Comment: Why the close votes? This question is  `a specific programming problem regarding software tools commonly used by programmers` and is an `answerable problem` as specified in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - `What topics can I ask about here?`   section.

Comment: @AviTurner Same help center. 4 th point: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow*

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I guess you are right. what is missing here is the `describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` part.. Although I often find questions like this one useful while googling...

Answer (score 3):

There's already a tool present, Parallel Stacks. To open it, Click on

> Debug -> Windows -> Parallel Stacks

You can have a quick view on how to work with Parallel Stacks at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd998398(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

This is the approach I use when I need to locate a leak:

1. Open a **memory profiler**.
   I use [perfmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx).
   [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42721/Best-Practices-No-5-Detecting-NET-application-memo) article has some material about setting perfmon and [@fmunkert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045938/detecting-memory-leak-in-mixed-environmentmanaged-unmanaged/11048467#11048467) also explains it rather well.
2. **Locate** an area in the code that you suspect that it is likely that the leak is in that area. This part is mostly depending on you having good guesses about the part of the code that is responsible for the issue.
3. **Push the Leak to the extreme**: Use labels and "goto" for isolating an area / function and repeat the suspicious code many times (a loop will work to. I find goto more convenient for this matter).
4. In the loop I have used a breakpoint that halted every 50 hits for examining the delta in the memory usage. Of course you can change the value to feet a noticeable leak change in your application.
5. If you have located the area that causes the leak, the memory usage should rapidly spike.
   If the Memory usage does not spike, repeat stages 1-4 with another area of code that you suspect being the root cause. If it does, continue to 6.
6. In the area you have found to be the cause, use same technique (goto + labels) to zoom in and isolate smaller parts of the area until you find the source of the leak (Please don't downvote me for the recursive step... :0) ).

Please note that the down sides of this method are:

1. If you are allocating an object in the loop, it's disposal should be also contained in the loop.
2. If you have more than one source of leak, It makes it harder to spot (yet still possible)

Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

If you have visual studio 2013 You can download the Microsoft Concurrency Visualizer for Visual Studio:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537632.aspx

It gives great insight in the application and threads currently running.

Synchronization, Sleeping, Blocking etc etc. 
Next to that you can also download the extension (found on the same page)

In my opinion a great tool (and best of all free)